# What do I need to install for IIS Tracer to install on Windows 7 with IIS 7.0?

Tags: windows, windows-7, iis-7

I could not install IIS tracer on a machine running Windows 7 and IIS 7.0 because IIS admin objects were not present. What do I need to do to have those objects created?

[image: IIS Tracer configuration dialog]

The important text of the error being: "You cannot install IISTracer ISAPI filter using this application if IIS Admin objects are not present on the destination computer. See help to install this filter manually."

Comment: In case anyone else may search for the error message in that screenshot (and like me not find a single hit, even in 2020), here it is, to help others find this thread in the future: "You cannot install IISTracer ISAPI filter using this application if IIS Admin objects are not present on the destination computer. See help to install this filter manually.""

Answer (score 1):

Note: You will need to run with admin rights even after this step in order to have IIS Tracer settings applet access the Metabase / Admin Objects.

In Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features on or off > Internet Information Services > Web Management Tools > IIS 6 Management Compatibility > IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility

[image: Windows 7 Features Dialog]

Bonus: On Server 2008:
Server Manager > Roles > Right-click Web Server (IIS) > Add Role Services
Management Tools (Installed) > IIS 6 Management Compatibility
Check both IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility and IIS 6 Management Console.

[image: Server 2008 version of dialog]

Comment: Thanks for that. So frustrating that the message is not more accurate, but of course it reflect how this tool was written near the turn of the century, when IIS 6 still reigned. Though the website for the tool says it was updated to support IIS 7 (no mention of 8 or above), I find no discussion there of this error or this workaround. Thanks for it.  Those who may not want to bother should consider the IIS "worker processes" monitor which has been available (though optional to install) since IIS 7.